# How do I get only the balance values as outputs from request_client.get_balance() function of Binance api?

Tags: python, trading, cryptoapi, cryptocurrency, binance

I just want to get the value of the balances as an output. I tried using '''json.loads''' but it gives me and error.

**Code**

```
request_client = RequestClient(api_key=API_KEY, secret_key=API_SECRET, 
url='https://fapi.binance.com')

result = request_client.get_balance()

print(result)
```

**Output**

[{"accountAlias":"XXXX","asset":"USDT","balance":"0.00000000","withdrawAvailable":"0.00000000","updateTime":1611266515660},{"accountAlias":"XXXX","asset":"BNB","balance":"0.00004992","withdrawAvailable":"0.00004992","updateTime":1611043014858},{"accountAlias":"XXXX","asset":"BUSD","balance":"0.00000000","withdrawAvailable":"0.00000000","updateTime":0}]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `result` variable is list with dictionaries inside. To get access to specific element in dictionary use `[position]` 0,1,2,3 etc....

To get specific value from dictionary we need to access it via `key`, in this case keys are: *accountAlias, asset, balance, withdrawAvailable and updateTime*.
Combining this methods gain you access to value inside `result` variable.

To get balance of first element(USDT) in dictionary use: `print(result[0]['balance'])`,

to get balance of second element(BNB) in dictionary use: `print(result[1]['balance'])`.

But if you want to get list of all balances at once(in one variable):
`a = [lst['balance'] for lst in result]`

**Output**:`['0.00000000', '0.00004992', '0.00000000']`